# How can I turn off the copy prompt in windows7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I'll need to copy huge directories with thousands of files and folders over another folder.
During the copy process when two files have the same name a dialog will appear and ask "What do you want to do?", I pick "Replace", I check "Do the same for remaining Items", I walk away and come back.....

Only to find the copy has been suspended, because I am being prompted again for the same thing for another folder.  So, it seems with the upgrade to windows7 I now have to babysit every copy operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should experiment with Windows 7's buit-in command, robocopy, which has a lot of options.  Run `robocopy /?` to see them all.

I would start with this command:

```
robocopy /mir c:\source d:\target
```

and then rerun it to see if it does what you need it to do.  If not, there may be an additional command line option that will work.

Comment: This looks pretty good.

Comment: +1 for Robocopy. In my humbug opinion doing large file copies via the command line (ideally with both the verify and restartable mode options turned on) is the only sane option on Windows. Using the GUI is just too unstable.

Answer (score 2):

You could use xcopy from the command line with the /y flag.  IF you want something more graphical [how to geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/news/supercopier-is-a-lightening-fast-alternative-windows-file-copier/6031/) was recommending SuperCopier as an alternative to windows explorer.

Answer (score 0):

You describe a feature every vanilla Windows (Explorer) is lacking.

You may have a look at [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php) which hooks into the copy operation of Explorer.

Alternatively you could use a Directory Commander like [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/index.htm) or [Directory Opus](http://www.gpsoft.com.au/). There are also others and especially free ones out there, but I haven't tested them exhaustively. Maybe you find this [list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_managers) helpful.